# Compile C programs for Android?

Tags: android, c, arm64, libc

I'm using an aarch64 Linux computer, and my Android phone is also an aarch64 Linux system.
When I compile a simple Hello World program and adb-pull it over to the Android phone and chmod +x it, I find that I cannot execute it. I believe I heard that Google does not use libc. Is that possibly the reason or is there something else going on?

Comment: Please add comments about how to configured your working environment, otherwise your question may be closed.  Needs more details about.

Comment: @alinsoar No not as comments. Instead the OP should ***[edit]*** the question to include all necessary details.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry, I meant "to comment more about his environment" (with the meaning of adding more details) .  Of course, in the question, not to comment section.

Comment: What do you mean by you cannot execute it? What is the error message?